# Why, after login by my own view, user is logged in on admin site but not on my views? Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I have situation where I wanted to check if my app works on production.
***When I start app locally, everythink works,*** but on **production** when I use my login form, user is logged in on django admin site, but on my user detail view, and another views, where in templates I use `request.user` I have error `exception.NoReverseMatch` in `{% url '' %}` tags, because `request.user` is `None`.

I asume that user isn't authenticated, but why?

My form:

```
class LoginForm(LoginForm):
    def clean(self):
        super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        if not self.user.is_active or self.user.is_deleted:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['account_inactive'])
        return self.cleaned_data
```

My view:

```
class LoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm


login_view = LoginView.as_view()
```

Here my urls:

```
app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path("redirect/", view=user_redirect_view, name="redirect"),
    path("<int:pk>/update/", view=user_update_view, name="update"),
    path("change_password", view=user_password_change_view, name="password_change"),
    path("<int:pk>/remove-user", view=user_remove_from_company_view, name="remove_user"),
    path("<int:pk>/update-role", view=profile_update_role, name="update_role"),
    path("<int:pk>/", view=user_detail_view, name="detail"),
    path("sign_up/", view=registration_view, name="registration"),
]
```

My User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name=_('Email address'),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last name'), max_length=20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('Date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(_('Deleted'), default=False)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(_('Stripe customer id'), 
max_length=19, blank=True, default='')

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['email']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.email})
```

Comment: `user is authenticated on admin site, but not on my views` what does it mean? what's an exception and example code which is throwing it?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc I corrected the question.

Comment: What does it mean local/production? Did you clean cookies and try login locally (or incognito mode)?
Do you use standard django login or some external package like `django-allauth`?

Comment: @MikeBr   By local I mean localhost, by production I mean app deployed on digitalocean. I use django cookiecutter template, so I run docker with production settings on digitalocean droplet. I use django-allauth.

Comment: What is your user detail view?

Comment: can you provide your `url conf` and which `id` you are passing for detail view?

Comment: How do you extend the Django's user model? Also show us your urls.py file.

Comment: @Subham I updated question with urls. I pass ```id``` of user.

Comment: @PedramParsian I extend user model by ```AbstractBaseUser```.

Comment: Do you have two settings files, one for local and a different one for production? Is there a settings file which is common to both environments?

Comment: @Rupin I have 3 settings files, one is base for local and production and two seperated for both of them (local.py, production.py). It's from django-cookiecutter template.

Comment: Have you set ```AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'``` in ```settings.py```?

Have you also included the login view in your urls? I don't see it there...

Comment: @KrystianK are you using different domains for admin views and custom views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `django-allauth` with different settings for local and production try set this in your local settings:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
```

**EDIT**

After read the new comments I also recommend to check the templates - maybe you have somewhere reference to wrong object - i.e. you calling the user from a related model whose object doesn't exist?

Comment: Which url address you see in the browser with the above error?

Comment: Url of my user detail view.

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

- either you are using different domains (including port number) for admin and for "your" views. Also you can check if `sessionid` cookie is set
- or you are checking permissions not correctly (@KrystianK please provide example in your question)
- otherwise there is a problem in user attributes `is_staff`, `is_superuser` or `is_active`